# Parent formset with childrens inline formsets

Tags: html, django, django-forms, formset, inline-formset

I'm trying to come up with the best approach for this problem. I have 2 models with 2 forms and 1 formset:

```
#models
class ModbusDevice(models.Model):
    ixModbusDevice = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    sModbusName = models.CharField(verbose_name='Device Name',max_length=100)
    iPort = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Port')
    iSlave = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Slave ID')
    sIP = models.GenericIPAddressField(verbose_name='IP Address')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'TModbusDevice'


class Register(models.Model):
    ixRegister = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    sRegisterName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    iStartingAddr = models.IntegerField()
    bRange = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ixIOType = models.ForeignKey(IOType)
    ixModbusDevice = models.ForeignKey(ModbusDevice)
    iOffset = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'TRegister'

#forms
class InitialRegisterFormset(BaseModelFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(InitialRegisterFormset, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.queryset = Register.objects.all()

class ModbusRegistersForm(ModelForm):
    ixIOType = ModelChoiceField(queryset=IOType.objects.all()),
    bRange = BooleanField(required=False)
    bRange.widget.attrs['data-form'] = 0

    class Meta:
        model = Register
        fields = ['sRegisterName','iStartingAddr','bRange','ixIOType','iOffset']
        widgets = {
                'sRegisterName': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Register Name','class': 'form-control', 'data-form': '0'}),
                'iStartingAddr': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Starting address','class': 'form-control','data-form': '0'}),
                'iOffset': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Address offset','class': 'form-control','data-form': '0'}),
            }
class CreateModbusForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ModbusDevice
        fields = ['sModbusName','iPort', 'iSlave', 'sIP']
        widgets = {
                'sModbusName': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Device Name','class': 'form-control','data-form': '0',}),
                'iPort': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Port','class': 'form-control','data-form': '0',}),
                'iSlave': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Slave id','class': 'form-control','data-form': '0',}),
                'sIP': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Modbus IP address','class': 'form-control','data-form': '0',})
            }
```

What I'm trying to do is create a formset of ModbusDevices along with their belonging registers(inline formset).

So far this is what I've managed to get:
[image]

I'm returning all existing modbus devices(in this example I only have 1 in my db) and 1 extra if the user wants to add a new device. In my registers is where I have a problem. Right now I'm returning all registers in my table and displaying them instead of displaying only the related registers. I'm not sure how I can go about iterating my device formset and accessing it's children belonging to the device.

Here is my view:

```
ModbusFormset = modelformset_factory(ModbusDevice, form=CreateModbusForm)

register_qset = Register.objects.all()
InlineRegisterFormset = None
if not register_qset:
    InlineRegisterFormset = inlineformset_factory(ModbusDevice, Register, form=ModbusRegistersForm, extra=1)
else:
    InlineRegisterFormset = inlineformset_factory(ModbusDevice, Register, form=ModbusRegistersForm, formset=InitialRegisterFormset,  extra=len(register_qset))

modbus_qset = ModbusDevice.objects.all()
devices = ModbusFormset(queryset=modbus_qset, prefix="modbus")

registers = InlineRegisterFormset(prefix="register")
```